# Is level set of sum of two continuous functions a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

$f^i: R^{n}\to R^{n}$  is a continuous function for $i=1,2$.

Let
$$M=\{(x,y)\in R^{2n}~|~f^1(x)+f^2(y)=0\}$$

Is $M$ a closed set? If not, can you give a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(x,y) = f^1(x) + f^2(y)$.  Then $F$ is continuous by hypothesis on $f^1,f^2$, and the set $M = F^{-1}\{0\}$.  Because of continuity, preimages of closed sets are closed, so $M$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

let  (xn, yn) is a sequence of M which tends to (x, y)

(on Rn, R2n, all norms are equivalent)

we choose the sup norm

So xn tends to x and yn tends to y .
as f1 and f2 are continuous then f1 (x) + f2 (y) tends to f1 (x) + f2 (y)

secondly f1 (xn) + f2 (yn) = 0 for (xn, yn) in M
 by uniqueness of the limit
f1 (x) + f2 (y) = 0 then (x, y) in M
by characterization of closed set by  sequences
M is closed.

Comment: Thank you, this is also a correct answer.

Comment: So give it an upvote, then.